# Azure API Management not honoring the operationId when importing open API spec

Tags: azure-api-management

I have swagger.json generated from Swashbuckle.  When importing the open API specification into Azure API management, it does not use the operationId as the name of the operation.  Instead it uses the description.  I have attached a sample of the JSON that produces the issue.

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "version": "v1",
    "title": "Route Manager API"
  },
  "paths": {
    "/api/account/Logout": {
      "post": {
        "tags": [ "Account" ],
        "summary": "Logs the current user out of the system.",
        "operationId": "ApiAccountLogoutPost",
        "consumes": [],
        "produces": [],
        "parameters": [],
        "responses": { "200": { "description": "Logout successfully performed" } }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

The following example is taken from the Microsoft documentation when importing Open API spec and seems to use the OperationId as the name (GetSessions) does display as the title for the function in API management.

```
  "paths": {
    "/sessions": {
      "get": {
        "description": "A list of sessions.  Optional parameters work as filters to reduce the listed sessions.",
        "operationId": "GetSessions",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "speakername",
            "in": "query",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "dayno",
            "in": "query",
            "description": "Format - int32.",
            "type": "integer"
          },
          {
            "name": "keyword",
            "in": "query",
            "type": "string"
          }
        ],
        "responses": { "200": { "description": "OK" } },
        "produces": [ "application/vnd.collection+json" ]
      }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APIM does honor operationId, it's value is used to form up operation id as an Azure resource. What you see on UI is operation title. It is wrong to use operationId as title because Open API spec says:

> Unique string used to identify the operation. The id MUST be unique among all operations described in the API. Tools and libraries MAY use the operationId to uniquely identify an operation, therefore, it is recommended to follow common programming naming conventions.

One would not want to follow common programming naming conventions with operation title. So "summary" field is used instead for operation title.

More details here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/apimanagement/2018/04/11/important-changes-to-openapi-import-and-export/

Comment: Oh Ok...I see it now.  My JSON provides a summary node which is used over the OpeationId.  Thanks.